# ios 8 app facebook integration recommendation

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, instagram, ios8

I am developing an app for iOS8 (also back versions compatible) . I need to Log-in using Facebook and get photos and album information of the user. I was looking around the web and found terminology like "Parse Framework" and "Graph API"
Is Graph API the old way and Parse Framework the recommended latest way ?
do they both apply for photos retrieval from Facebook account ? I also need to use instagram Log-in and photos for the same app does that change the choice between using Graph or Parse ?.

Comment: see my answer....may be helped......if you have any query then tell me.. i will help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are totally unaware about the terminologies Parse & Graph api.

> Is Graph API the old way and Parse Framework the recommended latest way ?

**No**
`Parse` is a baas(backend as service). Its a backend service that you will used to store your app data such as images,user data or anything something like sqlite database but its  own cloud.

`Graph api` is facebook api service that you will used to get the graph data such as posts, friends etc. Even if you have used the parse as the backend you have to use the graph api to get the posts from fb.